# SUPEE6788 and SQL statements in addFieldToFilter

Tags: collection, patches, collection-filtering, supee-6788, ce-1.9.2.2

At [SUPEE-6788 Technical Details](http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) the Magento people give examples about how to fix Magento modules. Anyway, I have some places I found after install the SUPEE6788 patch that isn't explained in examples maybe someone could help me with. I have this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('`main_table`.order_id', array('in' => $ordersIds));
```

I'm just wondering how to fix it? Like this: `('main_table .order_id',array('in" =>$ordersIds))` i.e. just remove the " ` " ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you cannot use arbitrary SQL expressions anymore, but you can still use the form `table_alias.field_name`, without backticks (``).